# Close the Find Tool in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, editor

How can I close this thing? It's really annoying. I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1.3 (Ultimate Edition) on Windows 10.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Focus the input field and press <kbd>Esc</kbd>.